# How to get the cumulative column from my sales table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following scenario

pid & month form a composite primary key .

```
pid month amount
1    1     10
2    2     15
1    2     20
1    3     10
3    3     4
2    3     6
```

Now the column to be generated with the table will be like this

```
pid month amount   sum
1    1     10      10
2    2     15      15
1    2     20      30
1    3     10      40
3    3     4       4
2    3     6       21
```

What should be the query ?

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.... what have you tried so far? We are not a regular forum where you ask a general question and we all give you answers. However many people here are will to help those who have at least attempted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will do the trick :

```
SELECT t1.*, sum(t2.amount)
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.pid = t2.pid AND t1.month >= t2.month
GROUP BY t1.pid, t1.month, t1.amount
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db350/7/0

Comment: Works ! Thanks a lot Fabien

Comment: can i use a recursive cte ?

Answer (score 2):

If using SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT *,SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY month ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)'Total'
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks but i was working on sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what version of SQL Server you are using but you should be able to use the following to get the running total in any version:

```
select t1.pid, 
  t1.month, 
  t1.amount,
  (select sum(t2.amount) 
   from yourtable t2
   where t1.pid = t2.pid
     and t2.month <= t1.month) total
from yourtable t1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b43a/6)

Comment: It doesn't work it fetches all Nulls in the total column

Comment: @user2718853 Using your sample data set it is working -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b43a/6